# Feature scaling in Linear Regression

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, feature-scaling

I always use `Linearregression()` class in sklearn library for creating a linear regression model. According to my understanding, we need feature scaling in linear regression when we use Stochastic gradient descent as a solver algorithm, as feature scaling will help in finding the solution in less number of iterations, so with `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor()` we need to scale the input. However, we dont need to scale the input with `Linearregression()` as it uses the closed form solution ( based on minimizing the sum of squared residuals). **So my first question is, is my understanding correct ?** **Now my second question is, I need to understand in details why exactly feature scaling will not help if we uses `Linearregression()` ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AAA,
Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer to your second question:

- `LinearRegression()` uses Normal Equation i.e. closed-form solution to get best parameters for a given solution. Hence, we don’t have iterative loops to find best solution. Therefore, feature scaling is not recommended. Whereas, algorithms that use gradient decent, scaling is recommended.